# SQL Table Headers Not Saved To Excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The following code is used to save data from an SQL table to excel. The problem is, it does not save table headers if the table is empty.

```
                worksheet4 = workbook.Sheets[4];
                worksheet4.Name = "Adjs ";

                SQL.DataTable dtAG = new SQL.DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(query4.ToString(), cn1))
                    {
                        da4.Fill(dtAG);

                    }
                }
                DataColumnCollection dcCollection4 = dtAG.Columns;
                for (int i = 1; i < dtAG.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
                {

                    for (int j = 1; j < dtAG.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 1)

                            worksheet4.Cells[i, j] = dcCollection4[j - 1].ToString();

                        else

                            worksheet4.Cells[i, j] = dtAG.Rows[i - 1][j - 1].ToString();

                    }

                }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the columns before you it start filling out the data:

```
int a = 1;
foreach(DataColumn dc in dtAG.Columns)
{
      worksheet4.Cells[1, a] = dc.ColumnName;
      a++;
}
```

and then just start from the next row:

```
for (int i = 2; i < dtAG.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < dtAG.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
    {
         worksheet4.Cells[i, j] = dtAG.Rows[i - 1][j - 1].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the header values like this: `ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "example";`

`[i, j]` has to be `[i+1,j]` if not, you over write your headings.